# Getting response from a website using Node.js

Tags: node.js, request

I am making a simple code in node using `request` to test if a website exist or not.
I want response if website exists with `statusCode 200`, if not then exit with `statusCode` 404

Here is my stuff

```
var http = require('http');
 var request = require('request');

    http.createServer(function (req , res) {

        res.write("hello");


        request('http://www.cutm.ac.in', function (error , response , body) {

            if(!error && response == 200){

                console.log(body);
            }
            else{
                console.log("hdsa");
            }
        });
    }).listen(9000);
        console.log("started");
```

If I am doing

```
if(!error && response == 200)
```

it's not working, but when I remove response == 200, I am getting the html codes.

Any help

Comment: "it's not working" — what does that mean? Does `console.log("hdsa");` run?

Comment: "when I remove response == 200, I am getting the html codes" — What suggests that `response` is some other value. Have you tried looking at it to see what it is?

Comment: Thanks but it's working with `statusCode`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var http = require('http');
 var request = require('request');

    http.createServer(function (req , res) {

        res.write("hello");


        request('http://www.cutm.ac.in', function (error , response , body) {

            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

                console.log(body);
            }
            else{
                console.log("hdsa");
            }
        });
    }).listen(9000);
        console.log("started");
```

Always check `statusCode` to get response status